# WindowServer Bookend log messages

Tags: macos, logs

I am getting lots of log messages in my 10.10 Server install.  This was an upgrade from 10.9.5. I will get hundreds of the Gesture Started and Gesture Ended messages in a second with different numbers (i.e. 503xxx becomes 504xxx).

```
9:41:46 AM WindowServer: 50386035501120 -- Bookend Type: 62 (Gesture Ended) conn: 0xf8c7, window 0x5e 
9:41:46 AM WindowServer: 50386035506584 ++ Bookend Type: 61 (Gesture Started) conn: 0xf8c7, window 0x5e 
9:41:46 AM WindowServer: *** Complete ***
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. Are you using BetterTouchTool?

Comment: @Brethil no I am not using that tool.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot describe how terribly annoying this was for me post Yosemite install as well. Your beloved mac would freeze as hundreds (thousands?) of log lines detailing gesture bookends would demand intense resources. Anyhow, here is the secret sauce.

**Note that multi-monitor preferences are going to be lost (screen arrangement, preferred display, etc)**

Step 1: move/backup your plist files

```
sudo mv /Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist ~/Desktop/
sudo mv ~/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.windowserver* ~/Desktop/
```

Step 2: Shutdown your mac

Step 3: Reset pram

```
press/hold Command+Option+P+R and press power button once
wait for two tones 
let go of the keys and allow your mac to boot normally
```

I hope it does the trick for you.

Comment: Since the questioner was using OS X Server I'm really glad to say that this answer worked for me on a non-server OS X as well.